# Select Element with CSS in complex HTML Structure

Tags: html, css

First of All, 
Here is my HTML

```
<section class="plans container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h2><img src="img/money.png" class="img-fluid mr-3" />Open A Ira And Get this tax deductables</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Standard</h4>
              <h2>$2000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan1.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Unlimited</h4>
              <h2>$4000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan2.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Platinum</h4>
              <h2>$6500</h2>
              <img src="img/plan3.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I want to select 2nd .plan element. 
Here is CSS I tried

```
.plans .container .row .plan:nth-child(1) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

But it didn't worked. It changed background of all 3 .plan elements.

[image: result got from my try]

What is the best way to select elements in these type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it will do your job.

```css
.plans .row > div:nth-child(2) .plan {
 background: red
 }
```

```html
<section class="plans container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h2><img src="img/money.png" class="img-fluid mr-3" />Open A Ira And Get this tax deductables</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Standard</h4>
              <h2>$2000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan1.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Unlimited</h4>
              <h2>$4000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan2.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Platinum</h4>
              <h2>$6500</h2>
              <img src="img/plan3.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: it selects .col-md-4 div instead of .plan div.

Comment: @MilanUptech you can thank me by giving upvote and accept my answer. if you want  :)

Comment: sure. I wasn't accepting due to time rules of StackOverFlow :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the div element before each div. This is because of the next structure:

```
Parent
  |-Child 1
  |  |-Child 1
  |-Child 2
  |  |-Child 1
  |-Child 3
  |  |-Child 1
```

As you can see, `.plan` isnt group in childs

```
.plans .container .row div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

Hode this helps

```css
.plans .container .row div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<section class="plans container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h2><img src="img/money.png" class="img-fluid mr-3" />Open A Ira And Get this tax deductables</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Standard</h4>
              <h2>$2000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan1.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Unlimited</h4>
              <h2>$4000</h2>
              <img src="img/plan2.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="plan">
              <h4>Platinum</h4>
              <h2>$6500</h2>
              <img src="img/plan3.png" class="img-fluid" />
              <p>The Amount is all Tax Deductable</p>
              <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: it selects .col-md-4 div instead .plan div.